# Java spring POST request status 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm following a tutorial and my POST request is getting a 404 response. I dont understand why.

I have rewatched the tutorial many times and compared with another project and still can't find the error.

I appreciate all the help possible

PersonController:

```
import model.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import service.PersonService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void addPerson(@RequestBody Person person){
        personService.addPerson(person);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
import dao.PersonDao;
import model.Person;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonDao personDao;

    @Autowired
    public PersonService(@Qualifier("fakeDao") PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public int addPerson(Person person){
        return personDao.insertPerson(person);
    }
}
```

A part of run:

```
2022-05-17 16:02:34.886 TRACE 120467 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    o.s.b.a.w.s.e.BasicErrorController:
    { [/error]}: error(HttpServletRequest)
    { [/error], produces [text/html]}: errorHtml(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)
2022-05-17 16:02:34.889 DEBUG 120467 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
```

Postman:

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBEVM.png)

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-05-17T15:02:39.240+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/v1/person"
}
```

Comment: Are you missing a `/` at the start of the path in `@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/person")`?

Comment: @f1sh, Spring must understand and put it before.

Comment: I think the problem here is that your `@RestController` bean was not found by default Spring's `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: @f1sh I tried the "/" before. Didnt worked.

Comment: I will recommend you to try to use directly `@ComponentScan`. You can find how to use it here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Comment: @SerhiiZhura I didn't undestandood the solution. OR at least I tried but I had some error with "<bean></bean>"  in the xml config aka 'pom.xml' ?!

Comment: @SerhiiZhura i added 'Configuration, EnableAutoConfiguration, ComponentScan' and still not working

Comment: @Felipe Silva Try add `required=false` into  `@ResponseBody` so if you are not sending any body will return 404 even url is correct. In other  way just check if you are sending any body

Comment: @DilermandoLima Hey, I added the required = false, and still getting a 404. I'm sending a body.